# Image not displaying on 2 iPad retina devices

Tags: css, image, ipad, responsive-design, retina

I'm a relative rookie with html/css. I build a site partly using a sitebuilder (Webflow), did some css tweaks, and have tested it across a lot of devices.

It works fine in all the other devices I've tested in, but unfortunately when I've tested it (remotely via Browserstack) the image on the right hand side doesn't seem to appear in 2 recent iPad retina devices.

The site is:

http://joemitchell.co/feelangstone_1/

Not sure what's going on. Would be very grateful if anyone knows what's going on and how I can fix it. Please note, I'm a relatively rookie with code, so please specific, step-by-step instructions would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: It works on my iPad, which is fairly recent, running the latest OS.

Comment: Thanks for check Ralph. I've tested the site and the image doesn't appear on: 1) iPad 4 Retina 7.0.3 or 2) iPad iOS 7. However it DOES appear fine on iPad Mini 2 and iPad Air 8.8. Anyone know what be going on?